# As $n$ increases, the value of $\sqrt[ne^{\pi}]{\pi}$ approaches $1$. Is there a name for this result?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, pi, eulers-number-e

> I was messing around with $\pi$ and $e$ on the Desmos calculator, and came up with the observation that this value:
>
> $$\sqrt[ne^{\pi}]{\pi}$$
>
> approaches $1$ as $n$ increases.

(To be clear, that's the $(ne^{\pi})$-th root of $\pi$.)

After around a half hour of looking on the internet and Wikipedia, I have yet to find anything explaining this. Is this something relevant to math (is it important)? If so, what is its name? I am making a compilation of cool things one can do with $\pi$, and would love to include a source/name for it.

Thank you, and have a good day!

Comment: The $n$th root of any positive real number tends to $1$ as $n\to\infty$. In this case the number you are taking the $n$th root of is just $\sqrt[e^\pi]{\pi}$.

Comment: Ah. I should've realized that that was the reason why. I wasn't aware that that applied to equations that have more to their root than just $n$.

Comment: @LizzyFoster the root need not be just $n$-th, you can also have, for example, some polynomial of $n$, in your example it is just $na$-th root of $\pi$, where $a$ is the constant you mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematically speaking, this phenomenon could be expressed by writing

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \pi^{1/(ne^\pi)} = 1$$

As it turns out, this phenomenon is not unusual -- for all positive real numbers $x$,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} x^{1/n} = 1$$

It should be fairly evident how this might apply to your case, since, for example, $\pi^{1/(ne^\pi)} = \left( \pi^{1/e^\pi} \right)^{1/n}$. The curiosity is, how to prove this? Well, since the exponential in this case is continuous, we can claim

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} x^{1/n} = x^{\lim_{n \to \infty} 1/n}$$

Obviously, as $n$ grows without bound, $1/n$ approaches $0$, so the exponent approaches zero, and thus your limit approaches $x^0 = 1$.

Comment: Wow! That's fascinating, and I quite honestly feel a bit silly for not considering that before posting!

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n=\sqrt[ne^{\pi}]{\pi}\implies\log(a_n)=\frac 1{ne^{\pi}}\log(\pi)=\frac{\log(\pi) }{e^\pi }\frac 1n$$ So, $\log(a_n)\to0$ and then $a_n\to 1$

Comment: Interesting. I also wouldn't have thought about it that way, but it makes sense.